# Right database for machine learning on 100 TB of data

Tags: mysql, mongodb, hadoop, machine-learning

I need to perform classification and clustering on about 100tb of web data and I was planning on using Hadoop and Mahout and AWS.  What database do you recommend I use to store the data?  Will MySQL work or would something like MongoDB be significantly faster?  Are there other advantages of one database or the other?  Thanks.

Comment: It depends on the type of data you're talking about. Is it relational? Numerical? Text? Does it have a complex internal structure? No database is magically faster than the others. You need to choose one that's the right fit for your data. Maybe flat files or [LevelDB](https://code.google.com/p/leveldb/) is the answer here.

Comment: They're html files and I'll be dealing with text.  Initially, Initially, I'll just pull all the text into a bag of words for each file, but I may use the html structure later on.

Comment: Unless you know the structure, this question is impossible to answer honestly.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to put the stuff somewhere. If so, I would just store it as a normal flat file in Hadoop DFS until you need to do something more to it.

Comment: Thanks Alex and tadman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest and most direct answer would be to just put the files directly in HDFS or S3 (since you mentioned AWS) and point Hadoop/Mahout directly at them. Other databases have different purposes, but Hadoop/HDFS is designed for exactly this kind of high-volume, batch-style analytics. If you want a more database-style access layer, then you can add Hive without too much trouble. The underlying storage layer would still be HDFS or S3, but Hive can give you SQL-like access to the data stored there, if that's what you're after.

Just to address the two other options you brought up: MongoDB is good for low-latency reads and writes, but you probably don't need that. And I'm not up on all the advanced features of MySQL, but I'm guessing 100TB is going to be pretty tough for it to deal with, especially when you start getting into large queries that access all of the data. It's more designed for traditional, transactional access.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know if there's a large difference in performance between S3 and HDFS?  I found documentation on replacing HDFS with S3, but not on the performance.